# ¿Cómo hago para que al presionar un botón aparezca un elemento div con una transición?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito que al presionar el botón "volver", aparezca el el div "inicio1" , pero quiero que esto no se vea tan brusco, mis preguntas son las siguientes:

- ¿Es posible hacer algo así?
- ¿Se hace combinando `CSS` y `JavaScript`?
- ¿Cómo se utiliza la propiedad `transition` en `CSS` de forma adecuada?
- ¿Se debe especificar cuándo se le quiere aplicar a un `background` o algo así?

tipo:

```
transition-duration:background 1sg.
```

```js
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::INICIO C1::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function inicio_1() {
  document.getElementById("C2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display = "block";

}
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::INICIO Di::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function inicio_2() {
  document.getElementById("D1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display = "block";
}
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::INICIO P1::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function inicio_3() {
  document.getElementById("P1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "inline";
}
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::LIMPIAR CAMPOS:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function limpiar_campos() {
  let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let resultados = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
    resultados[i].innerHTML = '';
  }
}



//::::::::::::::::::::::::::BOTÓN VOLVER:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function volver() {
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("D1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("P1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("C2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display = "none";
  //document.getElementById("C_0").style.display="none";
  // document.getElementById("C_1").style.display="none";
  limpiar_campos();




}

//::::::::::::::::::::::OBTENER VALORES DE LA LISTA:::::::::::::::::::::::::
let n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
let button = document.getElementById("button");

function hola1() {
  let obtenern1 = n1.value;
  let convertir = Number(obtenern1);

  //::::::::::::::::::::::OBTENER VALOR INGRESADO POR USUARIO QI::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  let contenido = document.getElementById("texto")
  let vector = [];
  let cambiados = [];

  let valor = contenido.value.split(",")

  let nuevoVector = valor.forEach((elemento) => {
    cambiados.push(Number(elemento))

  });
  let ordenado = cambiados.sort((x, y) => {
    return x - y
  })
  let conteo_lista = cambiados.length;
  //:::::::::::::::::::PROCESO DE OPERACIONES::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  let sumar_0 = conteo_lista + 1;
  let Qi_Di_Pi = convertir;

  //:::::::::::::::::::::::::ECUACIONES DE CUANTILES::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  let ecuacion_C = sumar_0 * Qi_Di_Pi / 4;
  let posicion = ecuacion_C.toString().indexOf('.5')

  console.log(posicion)
  if (posicion != -1) {
    let aproximacion_C = Math.round(ecuacion_C);
    let tomarvalores_C0 = ordenado[aproximacion_C - 1];
    let tomarvalores_C1 = ordenado[aproximacion_C - 2];
    let resultado_C = tomarvalores_C1 + tomarvalores_C0;
    resultado_C = resultado_C / 2;
    document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = "Lista ordenada:<br>" + ordenado + "<br>El resultado es:<br>" + ecuacion_C + "<br>El resultado final es:<br>" + resultado_C;

  } else {
    let aproximacion_C = Math.round(ecuacion_C);
    let tomarvalores_C0 = ordenado[aproximacion_C - 1];
    document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = "Lista ordenada:<br>" + ordenado + "<br>El resultado es:<br>" + ecuacion_C + "<br>El resultado final es:<br>" + tomarvalores_C0;


  }
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #fff;
}

h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dfe;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #39c;
}

#C2,
#D1,
#P1 {
  display: none;
}

#volver {
  display: none;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  background: #7AFFA9;
  transition-duration: s;
}

.inicio1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.contenedor {
  width: 60%;
  height: 70%;
  background: #7BE1E8;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
  display: none;
}

.C3 {
  Margin: 0px auto;
  background: #7A9DFF;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-radius: 2% 0% 0% 2%;
}


/* ------------------------DISEÑO DEL LOS BOTONES PRINCIPALES-------------------------------------*/

.inicio {
  color: #0099CC;
  /* Eliminar color de fondo */
  background: transparent;
  /* Grosor del borde, estilo de línea y color */
  border: 2px solid #0099CC;
  /* Añadir esquinas curvadas */
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Poner texto en mayúsculas */
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}


/* Al poner el curso encima (hover) */

.inicio:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="inicio1" class="inicio_inicio">
  <button class="inicio" id="Qi" onclick="inicio_1()">Qi</button>
  <button class="inicio" id="Di" onclick="inicio_2()">Di</button>
  <button class="inicio" id="Pi" onclick="inicio_3()">Pi</button>
</div>


<div class="contenedor" id="contenedor1">
  <div class="C3 " id="C2">
    <h4>Qi:<input type="text" id="n1" class="C1" maxlength="6" placeholder="Escribe el valor de (i)"></h4>
    <h4>Lista:<input type="texto" id="texto" class="" placeholder="Ej:3,4,51,2,3"></h4><br>
    <button id="button" onclick="hola1();" class="boton">Resolver</button>
    <h1 id="total1" class="h1"></h1>
  </div>


  <div id="D1" class="C3">
    <h4>Di:<input type="text" class="D2" id="n2" maxlength="6" a></h4>
    <h4>Lista:<input type="text" class="D2" id="texto2"></h4><br>
    <button id="button2" onclick="hola2()" class="boton">Resolver</button>
    <h1 id="total2" class="h1"></h1>


  </div>
  <div id="P1" class="C3">
    <h4>Pi:<input type="text" class="P2" id="n3" maxlength="6"></h4>
    <h4>Lista:<input type="text" class="P2" id="texto3"></h4><br>
    <button class="button3" onclick="hola3()" class="boton">Resolver</button>
    <h1 id="total3" class="h1"></h1>
  </div>

  <button id="volver" onclick="volver()" class="volver1">volver</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Camilo , te hace falta subir el codigo JS

Comment: Ya añadí el código JS.

Comment: Te sirvió alguna de las respuestas ? no olvides marcarla como aceptada para que sea de ayuda para otros usuarios.

Answer (score 1):

te dejo un ejemplo funcional, lo que hice fue quitar tu esta linea

```
document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display="block";
```

Y agregar `FadeIn` de `JQuery` con el cual defines la velocidad con la que quieres que aparezca el elemento

Prueba este snippet, espero sea lo que buscas.

```js
//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::INICIO C1::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function inicio_1(){

 $('#contenedor1').fadeIn(1000);// linea que agregue
  document.getElementById("C2").style.display="block" ;
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display="inline-block";
}

//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::INICIO Di::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function inicio_2(){
  document.getElementById("D1").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display="block";
}
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::INICIO P1::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function inicio_3(){
  document.getElementById("P1").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("volver").style.display="inline";
}
//::::::::::::::::::::::::::LIMPIAR CAMPOS:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function limpiar_campos() {
  let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let resultados = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
    resultados[i].innerHTML = '';
  }
}



//::::::::::::::::::::::::::BOTÓN VOLVER:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  function volver(){
    document.getElementById("inicio1").style.display="inline-block";
     document.getElementById("D1").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("P1").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("C2").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("volver").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("contenedor1").style.display="none";
      //document.getElementById("C_0").style.display="none";
     // document.getElementById("C_1").style.display="none";
     limpiar_campos();
      



  }

//::::::::::::::::::::::OBTENER VALORES DE LA LISTA:::::::::::::::::::::::::
let n1=document.getElementById("n1");
let button=document.getElementById("button");
function hola1(){
  let obtenern1= n1.value;
  let convertir=Number(obtenern1);

 //::::::::::::::::::::::OBTENER VALOR INGRESADO POR USUARIO QI::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 let contenido = document.getElementById("texto")
        let vector = [];
        let cambiados = [];

          let valor = contenido.value.split(",")
             
          let nuevoVector = valor.forEach((elemento) => {
            cambiados.push(Number(elemento))
            
          });
          let ordenado = cambiados.sort((x, y) => {
            return x - y
          })
          let conteo_lista=cambiados.length;
 //:::::::::::::::::::PROCESO DE OPERACIONES::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 let sumar_0=conteo_lista+1;
 let Qi_Di_Pi=convertir;

 //:::::::::::::::::::::::::ECUACIONES DE CUANTILES::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 let ecuacion_C=sumar_0*Qi_Di_Pi/4;
let posicion = ecuacion_C.toString().indexOf('.5')

console.log(posicion)
if (posicion != -1) {
  let aproximacion_C=Math.round(ecuacion_C);
  let tomarvalores_C0= ordenado[aproximacion_C-1];
  let tomarvalores_C1= ordenado[aproximacion_C-2];
  let resultado_C=tomarvalores_C1+tomarvalores_C0;
  resultado_C=resultado_C/2;
  document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML="Lista ordenada:<br>"+ordenado+"<br>El resultado es:<br>"+ecuacion_C+"<br>El resultado final es:<br>"+resultado_C;

}else{
  let aproximacion_C=Math.round(ecuacion_C);
  let tomarvalores_C0= ordenado[aproximacion_C-1];
  document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML="Lista ordenada:<br>"+ordenado+"<br>El resultado es:<br>"+ecuacion_C+"<br>El resultado final es:<br>"+tomarvalores_C0;


}
}
```

```css
body{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #fff;
}
h4{
    display: inline-block;
}
input{
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#dfe ;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #39c;

}
#C2,#D1, #P1{
    display: none;
}
#volver{
    display: none;
}
.h1{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    background:#7AFFA9;
    transition-duration: s;

}

.inicio1{
    width: 50%;
}
.contenedor{
    width: 60%;
    height: 70%;
    background: #7BE1E8;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
    display: none;

}
.C3{
    Margin:0px auto;
    background: #7A9DFF;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    border-radius: 2% 0% 0% 2%;
}
/* ------------------------DISEÑO DEL LOS BOTONES PRINCIPALES-------------------------------------*/
.inicio{
color: #0099CC;
/* Eliminar color de fondo */
background: transparent;
/* Grosor del borde, estilo de línea y color */
border: 2px solid #0099CC;
/* Añadir esquinas curvadas */
border-radius: 6px;
/* Poner texto en mayúsculas */
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn1 {
      background-color: white; 
      color: black; 
      border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}
/* Al poner el curso encima (hover) */
.inicio:hover {
      background-color: #008CBA;
      color: white;
 }
 
 .transicionCss {
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
 }
 .mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="inicio1" class="inicio_inicio">
    <button class="inicio" id="Qi" onclick="inicio_1()">Qi</button>
    <button class="inicio" id="Di" onclick="inicio_2()">Di</button>
    <button class="inicio" id="Pi" onclick="inicio_3()">Pi</button>
</div>


<div class="contenedor" id="contenedor1">
    <div class="C3 " id="C2">
    <h4>Qi:<input type="text" id="n1" class="C1" maxlength="6" placeholder="Escribe el valor de (i)"></h4>
    <h4>Lista:<input type="texto" id="texto" class="" placeholder="Ej:3,4,51,2,3"></h4><br>
    <button id="button" onclick="hola1();" class="boton">Resolver</button>
    <h1 id="total1" class="h1"></h1>
    </div>


<div id="D1" class="C3">
<h4>Di:<input type="text" class="D2" id="n2" maxlength="6"a></h4>
<h4>Lista:<input type="text" class="D2" id="texto2"></h4><br>
<button id="button2" onclick="hola2()" class="boton">Resolver</button>
<h1 id="total2" class="h1"></h1>


</div>
<div id="P1" class="C3">
    <h4>Pi:<input type="text" class="P2" id="n3" maxlength="6"></h4>
    <h4>Lista:<input type="text" class="P2" id="texto3"></h4><br>
    <button class="button3" onclick="hola3()" class="boton">Resolver</button>
    <h1 id="total3" class="h1"></h1>
</div>

<button id="volver" onclick="volver()" class="volver1">volver</button>
</div>
<script src="ju.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso tienes que hacer con transition de css pero no se ve nada de eso en tu código

Answer (score 0):

Para jugar con la aparición de elementos, puedes utilizar clases auxiliares de CSS.

Mira el ejemplo que te propongo a continuación:

```css
h1 {
  color: rgb(184, 32, 32);
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 30px 0;
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.h1--disabled {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="h1--disabled" id="title1">Primer titulo</h1>
  <h1 class="h1--disabled" id="title2">Segundo titulo</h1>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="activateTitle(1)">Muestra titulo 1</button>
  <button onclick="activateTitle(2)">Muestra titulo 2</button>
</body>

<script>
  function activateTitle(titleNumber) {
    document.getElementById(`title${titleNumber}`)
      .classList.remove('h1--disabled');
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Acá los títulos que tienen la clase `.h1--disabled` inician ocultos y mediante Javascript ejecutamos una función que se encarga de remover esta clase. Al removerse ya que los títulos tienen transiciones vas a visualizar los cambios desde los estados puestos en la clase `.h1--disabled` hasta su estado original.